# SLIDE UITableView headers OVER the previous header instead of PUSH

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a simple UITableView that has a custom header view created in viewForHeaderInSection.

The standard behavior in iOS is that when a new section header reaches the top of the tableview, it will push the previous header view off screen.

I would like to have the header view slide over (on top) of the previous header view instead of push it. I have found this website as a potential option: [Sliding Header Views](http://blog.chpwn.com/post/6378544658)

I can't quite figure out what to do as this blog post has no code samples. Anyone have any idea on how to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: That post is about a table header view, not about section header views.

Comment: After reading it I realize I got the two mixed up, you are indeed correct. Any clue how to accomplish this with section headers?

Comment: `UITableView` doesn't support what you want. You will have to roll your own.